# include css file in head tag without external libraries

Tags: html, node.js

How could I put this css file  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css">` inside `head` tag using Node?

This is what I did so far:

```
response.writeHead(200,{
    'Content-Type' : 'text/html',
});
response.end('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css">');
```

That winds up doing this:

```
<body><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css"></head></body>
```

How can I get the link and head elements outside of the body element where they should be?

Comment: `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css"></head>` ?

Comment: Uh...  Where else would you put it?

Comment: I tried that way with `response.end()` and this tag is put inside body tag like this `<body><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css"></head></body>`.

Comment: @Clément Malet smart dude :D i think he wants to put the link in the head with the help of node.js

Comment: Uh oh. We just had a clash of edits. Sorry, whoever else was editing this question when I saved mine. EDIT: I think I fixed it. I hope that didn't confuse anything!

Comment: well I think in order to render dynamic css that would be possible using less however in the head I believe it is not feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
response.end('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css"><body>Your page here</body>');
```

or this:

```
response.end('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/main.css"><div>Your page here</div>');
```

Browsers will automatically put every tags into `head` until they catch a tag, which is only used inside `body` by default `(body,span,div,...)`. Then they move the rest of the page into `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to include the tag using javascript, try this:

```
var el = document.createElement("link");
el.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet/less");
el.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
el.setAttribute("href", "path_to_my_css.css");
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: You can't do this in node.